# how to display hello world text in ionic 2 using typescript?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to learn ionic 2 using type script .could you please tell me how to 
display hello world text in ionic 2 using typescript ?
I am able to display **hello world** text in angular 2.I want to use ionic 2 and display text .

here is my code where is used **angular 2** 
http://plnkr.co/edit/xd0TbWO5deHB7xTjXibR?p=preview

could you please tell what are library of ionic 2  need to include to display text.
here is ionic 2 documentation
http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/tutorial/
// Code goes here

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';


@Component({
  selector:'app',
  template:'<div>hello</div>'

})

class App{}


bootstrap(App)
```

please share plunker

Answer (score 0):

In Ionic2, you don't use the `@Component` decorator but `@App` and `@Page` ones. With the `@App` one, you don't need to bootstrap your application. The corresponding class is automatically defined as main element / entry point of your application.

If you want to display an hello world text, simply generate with the `ionic start` command. For example:

```
$ ionic start MyIonic2Project --v2
```

Then you can reach the application class under the `app` folder (in the `app.js` file. To display a simple hello world, you could try this:

```
import 'es6-shim';
import {App, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import {StatusBar} from 'ionic-native';

@App({
  template: `
    <div>Hello world</div>
  `,
  config: {},
  providers: [ ]
})
export class MyApp {
  static get parameters() {
    return [[Platform]];
  }

  constructor() {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    });
  }
}
```

Notice that ES6 is used within the generated project.

Comment: can we make plunker  ?

Comment: Sorry it's not possible to provide you a plunkr in this case since ionic2 projects have a particular structure and build. You can generate very easily a project with the `ionic start` command. To start it, simply execute `ionic serve` after...